# Reset print spooler using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

We are continuously having a problem with our shared printers, (the shared printers are connected to a PC). resetting the print spooler solves our problem but we have to do it every morning. so I'm thinking to put a python file that would give admin rights and reset the print spooler by just clicking the file. can anyone help me with this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the win32serviceutil library

```
import win32serviceutil
win32serviceutil.RestartService("Spooler", ".")
```

The first argument is the name of the Service, I guess print spooler would be same name as this on your machine too. The second argument is the machine name or dot "." for local machine.

Remember, as you mentioned this will require admin privileges to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Windows OS`, you might try using `startfile` from `os` following way, providing path to your file as argument:

```
import os
os.startfile("path_to_file")
```

As [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) states `os.startfile`:

> Start a file with its associated application.
>
> When operation is not specified or 'open', this acts like
>   double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer, or giving the file name
>   as an argument to the start command from the interactive command
>   shell: the file is opened with whatever application (if any) its
>   extension is associated.